# Is there a Drupal 8 alternative for Inline Entity Form (to create an item while adding a reference)?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a Family content type and a Person content type. A Family has an [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field to one or more Persons.

The normal workflow requires me to first create the Persons, then create the Family and then add the Persons to the Family, but I want to create the Family first and create persons while adding them.

This is achieved in Drupal 7 with the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). Is there something like that for Drupal 8? Any alternative?

Comment: do you found a solution?

Comment: I gave up on doing that project on Drupal, so in the end I did not thoroughly try any of the options given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the alpha version and the dev version of the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

@webflo created an inline entity form port, I haven't tried it yet: https://github.com/webflo/inline_entity_form

Comment: I also found another port (that seems to be a fork of the one you linked):
* https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/axe312/2425359
* https://github.com/axe312ger/inline_entity_form

Comment: It would have been just as invalid by now anyway. It's now on d.o, so the answer below is the correct one now.

Answer (score 3):

There is another promising alternative is the [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module:

> Goal of this module is to provide a generic entity
>   browser/picker/selector. It can be used in any context where one needs
>   to select few entities and do something with them.
>
> Possible use cases:
>
> - powerfull entity reference widget,
> - embedding entities into wysiwyg,
> - you name it!

Comment: Entity Browser module allows you to select (browse for) entities that are already created. It does not allow you to create new entities. You can, however, use Entity Browser with Inline Entity Form - use entity browser as the mechanism to search for your entity (instead of inline entity form's autocomplete feature). I'm using inline entity form on a D8 site (not live yet) and it's working very well.