# How can I imitate the features of Node Reference and Node Reference URL in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities

In Drupal 8 we do not (at least currently) have the Node Reference and Node Reference URL Widget modules. How do I replicate their features?

I have a content type, let's say 'Book'. I also have a content type of 'Review'. Right now, the 'Review' content type has a reference field to 'Book'. A user can create a new 'Book' whenever they want just fine. Using the beta Form Block module for Drupal 8, I've embedded the node create form for 'Review' so that a user can create a new review from the bottom of the 'Book' page.

How can I have that newly created 'Review' automatically set the 'Book' as its reference node? Understandable I haven't seen a Drupal 8 module for it so I don't mind writing some code but I don't know where to start.

Comment: An alternative: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149480/inline-entity-form-in-drupal-8-create-item-while-adding-a-reference